# Pythonic way of setting a default

Tags: python, default-value

Is there a simple way of of setting a default in python - specifically setting a default in a dict?

For instance, let's say I have a dict called `foo`, which may or may not have something assigned on the key `bar`. The verbose way of doing this is:

```
if not foo.has_key('bar'):
  foo['bar'] = 123
```

One alternative would be:

```
foo['bar'] = foo.get('bar',123)
```

Is there some standard python way of doing this - something like the following, but that actually works?

```
foo['bar'] ||= 123
```

Comment: don't use `has_key()` use `'bar' in foo` to test for membership.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Why? has_key seems more explicit to me - is there some case where 'bar' in foo is more appropriate? Besides when foo isn't necessarily a dict?

Comment: `has_key()` is deprecated http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key (it is removed since python3.0). The reason might be "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: @J. F. Sebastian - good to know - thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't anyone read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)?

```
foo.setdefault('bar', 123)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check out [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: +1 Since that looks interesting for future purpose. Unfortunately, right now, I'm dealing with `request.session` in Django, so I can't redefine it to be a `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

(Wrong first part of the answer edited away)

`Dict`s have a `setdefault()` method that works just as `get()`, only it inserts the value if the key was missing.

```
foo.setdefault('bar', 123)
```

Cheers.

Comment: `foo.get('bar') or 123` is quite different than checking `foo.has_key('bar')`.  Consider `foo['bar'] = 0`.